# Error while trying to insert into Hive table with Spark 3.1.2: Can only write data to relations with a single path

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

The insret statment from Java code:
INSERT INTO table1 PARTITION (part1,part2) SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE_APPEND TEMP_TABLE

The excetpion stack trace:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only write data to relations with a single path.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:221)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators$(AnalysisHelper.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:216)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:618)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:613)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To make it simple, just running a simple insert via spark-sql from command line results in this same error spark-sql> insert into maor.maor_cdrs_rejected values (0,null,0,timestamp '2021-11-03 00:00:00',0,0);
Error in query: Can only write data to relations with a single path.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem....
The issue was a parameter in spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.sql.hive.manageFilesourcePartitions=false
```

It was set to false for some reason (the default is true).
Commneting this line solved the problem